# Can't Change Space Between list-item in XSL-FO

Tags: list, xsl-fo

It doesn't appear the `provisional-label-separation` attribute effects the spacing at all.  I have also tried `margin-*`, `padding-*`, `space-before`, and `space-after` but the space between list items still won't change.  How can I change the vertical space between list-items in a list like this (I am rendering to PDF, if that makes a difference)?

```
<fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts="3mm" 
               provisional-label-separation="3mm" 
               space-after="3mm" >

    <fo:list-item>
        <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
            <fo:block>&#x2022;</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-label>
        <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()" font-size="9pt">
            <fo:block>Day care or nanny expenses</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-body>
    </fo:list-item>

    <fo:list-item>
        <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
            <fo:block>&#x2022;</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-label>
        <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()" font-size="9pt">
            <fo:block>Field trips</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-body>
    </fo:list-item>

    <fo:list-item>
        <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
            <fo:block>&#x2022;</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-label>
        <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()" font-size="9pt">
            <fo:block>School supplies</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-body>
    </fo:list-item>

    <fo:list-item>
        <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
            <fo:block>&#x2022;</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-label>
        <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()" font-size="9pt">
            <fo:block>Music lessons and other extracurricular activities</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-body>
    </fo:list-item>

</fo:list-block>
```

Comment: What FO processor do you use?

Comment: @mzjn How do I find out?  I am using C#.

Comment: @mzjn I have a reference in my project to `fop` which I believe is Formatting Objects Processor.

Comment: @mzjn Version says, "0.0.0.0" but Runtime version (version of the .NET runtime this assembly was compiled against) says, "v2.0.50727."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To change the vertical space between list-items, use `space-after` (or perhaps `space-before`) *on the list-items*:

```
<fo:list-item space-after="5mm">
  <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
     <fo:block>&#x2022;</fo:block>
  </fo:list-item-label>
  <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()" font-size="9pt">
       <fo:block>Day care or nanny expenses</fo:block>
  </fo:list-item-body>
</fo:list-item>
```

`provisional-label-separation` specifies the provisional distance between the end of the list-item-label and the start of the list-item-body (i.e., it is a horizontal distance). See http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#d0e12377.

Comment: Thanks, good job.  I thought I tried this but I guess I didn't.  **Note:** This also excepts negative margins.